# Slice string into letters

Tags: string, go

How to slice one string in Go language into array of string letters it contains?

For example, turn string "abc" into array "a", "b", "c".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to runes, for example

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        s := "Hello, 世界"
        for i, r := range s {
                fmt.Printf("i%d r %c\n", i, r)
        }
        fmt.Println("----")
        a := []rune(s)
        for i, r := range a {
                fmt.Printf("i%d r %c\n", i, r)
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/NElx0y6z8l)

---

Output:

```
i0 r H
i1 r e
i2 r l
i3 r l
i4 r o
i5 r ,
i6 r  
i7 r 世
i10 r 界
----
i0 r H
i1 r e
i2 r l
i3 r l
i4 r o
i5 r ,
i6 r  
i7 r 世
i8 r 界
```

---

From the link:

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of runes type yields a slice containing the individual Unicode code points of the string. If the string is empty, the result is []rune(nil).

Answer (score 23):

Use strings.Split on it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",strings.Split("abc", ""))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/1tNfu0iyHS

Answer (score 12):

I think [`Split`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) is what you're looking for:

```
func Split(s, sep string) []string
```

If `sep` is an empty `string`, it will split the string into single characters:

> Split slices s into all substrings separated by sep and returns a slice of the substrings between those separators. **If sep is empty, Split splits after each UTF-8 sequence. It is equivalent to SplitN with a count of -1**.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to split.

```
var userString = "some string to split"

newArr:= strings.Split(userString, "")       // split on each char 

fmt.Println(newArr[2])                       // will print "m"
```