# Split string by length in Golang

Tags: string, split, go, string-length

Does anyone know how to split a string in Golang by length?

For example to split "helloworld" after every 3 characters, so it should ideally return an array of "hel" "low" "orl" "d"?

Alternatively a possible solution would be to also append a newline after every 3 characters..

All ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, some programming might help here? Like `s[n:n+3]+"\n"`?

Answer (score 25):

Make sure to **[convert](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)** your [string](http://blog.golang.org/strings) into a slice of rune: see "[Slice string into letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18556693/6309)".

`for` automatically converts `string` to `rune` so there is no additional code needed in this case to convert the `string` to `rune` first.

```
for i, r := range s {
    fmt.Printf("i%d r %c\n", i, r)
    // every 3 i, do something
}
```

`r[n:n+3]` will work best with a being a slice of rune.

The index will increase by *one* every rune, while it might **increase by more than one for every byte** in a [slice of string](http://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_12.): "世界": `i` would be 0 and 3: a character (rune) can be formed of multiple bytes.

---

For instance, consider `s := "世a界世bcd界efg世"`: 12 runes. (see <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/MdsEq53DfP)</kbd>)

If you try to parse it byte by byte, you will miss (in a naive split every 3 chars implementation) some of the "index modulo 3" (equals to 2, 5, 8 and 11), because the index will increase past those values:

```
for i, r := range s {
    res = res + string(r)
    fmt.Printf("i %d r %c\n", i, r)
    if i > 0 && (i+1)%3 == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("=>(%d) '%v'\n", i, res)
        res = ""
    }
}
```

The output:

```
i  0 r 世
i  3 r a   <== miss i==2
i  4 r 界
i  7 r 世  <== miss i==5
i 10 r b  <== miss i==8
i 11 r c  ===============> would print '世a界世bc', not exactly '3 chars'!
i 12 r d
i 13 r 界
i 16 r e  <== miss i==14
i 17 r f  ===============> would print 'd界ef'
i 18 r g
i 19 r 世 <== miss the rest of the string
```

But if you were to iterate on runes (`a := []rune(s)`), you would get what you expect, as the index would increase one rune at a time, making it easy to aggregate exactly 3 characters:

```
for i, r := range a {
    res = res + string(r)
    fmt.Printf("i%d r %c\n", i, r)
    if i > 0 && (i+1)%3 == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("=>(%d) '%v'\n", i, res)
        res = ""
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i 0 r 世
i 1 r a
i 2 r 界 ===============> would print '世a界'
i 3 r 世
i 4 r b
i 5 r c ===============> would print '世bc'
i 6 r d
i 7 r 界
i 8 r e ===============> would print 'd界e'
i 9 r f
i10 r g
i11 r 世 ===============> would print 'fg世'
```

Comment: It is very ineffective because of string concatenations. There are answers that don't use them

Answer (score 15):

Here is another variant [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/obc9_0kiDgL).
It is by far more efficient in terms of both speed and memory than other answers. If you want to run benchmarks here they are [benchmarks](https://github.com/igrmk/golang-chunks-benchmarks). In general it is 5 times faster than the previous version that was a fastest answer anyway.

```
func Chunks(s string, chunkSize int) []string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    if chunkSize >= len(s) {
        return []string{s}
    }
    var chunks []string = make([]string, 0, (len(s)-1)/chunkSize+1)
    currentLen := 0
    currentStart := 0
    for i := range s {
        if currentLen == chunkSize {
            chunks = append(chunks, s[currentStart:i])
            currentLen = 0
            currentStart = i
        }
        currentLen++
    }
    chunks = append(chunks, s[currentStart:])
    return chunks
}
```

Please note that the index points to a first byte of a rune on iterating over a string. The rune takes from 1 to 4 bytes. Slicing also treats the string as a byte array.

PREVIOUS SLOWER ALGORITHM

The code is here [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zP1XD7-mdes). The conversion from bytes to runes and then to bytes again takes a lot of time actually. So better use the fast algorithm at the top of the answer.

```
func ChunksSlower(s string, chunkSize int) []string {
    if chunkSize >= len(s) {
        return []string{s}
    }
    var chunks []string
    chunk := make([]rune, chunkSize)
    len := 0
    for _, r := range s {
        chunk[len] = r
        len++
        if len == chunkSize {
            chunks = append(chunks, string(chunk))
            len = 0
        }
    }
    if len > 0 {
        chunks = append(chunks, string(chunk[:len]))
    }
    return chunks
}
```

Please note that these two algorithms treat invalid UTF-8 characters in a different way. First one processes them as is when second one replaces them by `utf8.RuneError` symbol (`'\uFFFD'`) that has following hexadecimal representation in UTF-8: `efbfbd`.

Comment: This should be added to the standard library.

Comment: You can improve performance over this by using `strings.Builder`, see [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ATQimhjbueA). Benchmarks [here](https://github.com/ardnew/golang-chunks-benchmarks/tree/master)

Comment: @ardnew Thanks a lot for pointing it out! It shows that copying is a performance hit. However this builder does some copying by itself and it is not needed here. Instead I came up with even faster version that I will post here soon

Answer (score 6):

Also needed a function to do this recently, see [example usage here](https://play.golang.org/p/52gDebefno)

```
func SplitSubN(s string, n int) []string {
    sub := ""
    subs := []string{}

    runes := bytes.Runes([]byte(s))
    l := len(runes)
    for i, r := range runes {
        sub = sub + string(r)
        if (i + 1) % n == 0 {
            subs = append(subs, sub)
            sub = ""
        } else if (i + 1) == l {
            subs = append(subs, sub)
        }
    }

    return subs
}
```

Comment: It is very ineffective because of string concatenations. There are answers that don't use them

Answer (score 5):

Here is another example (you can try it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/n0mOHHTyPq0)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func ChunkString(s string, chunkSize int) []string {
    var chunks []string
    runes := []rune(s)

    if len(runes) == 0 {
        return []string{s}
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(runes); i += chunkSize {
        nn := i + chunkSize
        if nn > len(runes) {
            nn = len(runes)
        }
        chunks = append(chunks, string(runes[i:nn]))
    }
    return chunks
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ChunkString("helloworld", 3))
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(ChunkString("helloworld", 3), "\n"))
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer here. However `len(runes)` check looks unnecessary. You can check `len(s)` and return nil or empty array. This way you can define `runes` and `chunks` after this check

Comment: Actually I wrote my own answer now that is more effective

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution using regex

re := regexp.MustCompile(`(\S{3})`)
x := re.FindAllStringSubmatch("HelloWorld", -1)
fmt.Println(x)

https://play.golang.org/p/mfmaQlSRkHe

Comment: Didi u run it in The Go Playground? Could you pls let me know wht u didnt understand?

Comment: should be `FindAllString` instead of `FindAllStringSubmatch`, no?

Comment: this is by far the best example. Judging by the number of upvotes it has, it seems go programmers like to write lots of code!

Comment: this losts the last item. DON'T USE.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 3 version to implement the function, the function named "splitByWidthMake" is fastest.

These functions ignore the unicode but only the ascii code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "math"
)

func splitByWidthMake(str string, size int) []string {
    strLength := len(str)
    splitedLength := int(math.Ceil(float64(strLength) / float64(size)))
    splited := make([]string, splitedLength)
    var start, stop int
    for i := 0; i < splitedLength; i += 1 {
        start = i * size
        stop = start + size
        if stop > strLength {
            stop = strLength
        }
        splited[i] = str[start : stop]
    }
    return splited
}



func splitByWidth(str string, size int) []string {
    strLength := len(str)
    var splited []string
    var stop int
    for i := 0; i < strLength; i += size {
        stop = i + size
        if stop > strLength {
            stop = strLength
        }
        splited = append(splited, str[i:stop])
    }
    return splited
}

func splitRecursive(str string, size int) []string {
    if len(str) <= size {
        return []string{str}
    }
    return append([]string{string(str[0:size])}, splitRecursive(str[size:], size)...)
}

func main() {
    /*
    testStrings := []string{
        "hello world",
        "",
        "1",
    }
    */

    testStrings := make([]string, 10)
    for i := range testStrings {
        testStrings[i] = strings.Repeat("#", int(math.Pow(2, float64(i))))
    }

    //fmt.Println(testStrings)

    t1 := time.Now()
    for i := range testStrings {
        _ = splitByWidthMake(testStrings[i], 2)
        //fmt.Println(t)
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(t1)
    fmt.Println("for loop version elapsed: ", elapsed)


    t1 = time.Now()
    for i := range testStrings {
        _ = splitByWidth(testStrings[i], 2)
    }
    elapsed = time.Since(t1)
    fmt.Println("for loop without make version elapsed: ", elapsed)




    t1 = time.Now()
    for i := range testStrings {
        _ = splitRecursive(testStrings[i], 2)
    }
    elapsed = time.Since(t1)
    fmt.Println("recursive version elapsed: ", elapsed)

}
```

Comment: over-engineering, this is a simple problem.

Comment: this does not work for utf8